# Prove that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \cos(ax) = a^n \cos (ax + \frac{n\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

- **Question**

  Prove that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \cos(ax) =  a^n \cos (ax + \frac{n\pi}{2})$

---

I could calculate the first few derivatives of $\cos(ax)$ and consequently observe the pattern that unfolds, which in turn I can then correlate with $a^n \cos (ax + \frac{n\pi}{2})$.

However, I'm curious for a proof that does not rely on so many *words*, rather something more concrete(could I put it that way?).

I would include some of my attempts, but it's all rather trivial.

---

Comment: What you probably look for is induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $\cos ' (x)= -\sin (x) = \cos(x + \pi/2)$ and $\sin'(x) = \cos(x) = \sin(x+\pi/2)$, this is just a consequence of the chain rule and the linearity of the derivative.

Comment: This completes what I initially intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Let $a, x$ be real numbers. Observe that
$$ 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ia x}=(ia)^n e^{ia x}=a^n e^{in \frac{\pi}{2}}e^{ia x}=a^n e^{i(ax + \frac{n\pi}{2})}
$$
since $$ \cos x = \Re \:e^{ix}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},$$ you easily get
$$ 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\cos(ax)=a^n \cos \left(ax + \frac{n\pi}{2}\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach: from the Euler representation $\cos x=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{ix}+\operatorname{e}^{-ix}}{2}$ we have
$$
\frac{\operatorname{d^n}}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\cos(ax)=\frac{(ia)^n\operatorname{e}^{iax}+(-ia)^n\operatorname{e}^{-iax}}{2}=a^n\cos\left(a+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
since $(\pm i)^n=\operatorname{e}^{\pm in\frac{\pi}{2}}$.